# Font that is used in the Nicholls Colonels logo

Tags: font-identification

[image]

I have checked in many like  sites but could not get a proper answer. The given image is the logo of [Nicholls Colonels](http://www.geauxcolonels.com/), which is a baseball team.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for a similar font: There are many like it under the [**Old School category**](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=104&text=Nicholls) at DaFont, just waiting for a skew to be applied.

At a glance, looks like the closest is [**Nebraska**](http://www.dafont.com/nebraska.font?text=Nicholls). With a faux-italic applied in Photoshop, it looks like this:

[image: Nebraska Font]

---

If you are designing something for the Nicholls athletics program, **stop**. They should have a graphics department to get what you need. For an institution of this size, you do not want the burden of maintaining their identity on your shoulders.

The university has available outlining their Graphic Identity Standards available for public viewing [**here**](http://www.nicholls.edu/documents/nicholls/nicholls_identity_graphic_standards.pdf). There are a few font guidelines listed, but none for the typefaces used for the logo you are looking for.

It is in your best interest to contact the Director of University Printing & Design Services (on page 2) to acquire the necessary materials for your design.